# Word VBA: Underlining specific words within a bullet/paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

So lets assume we have a table with only 1 column. And within each **cell** there can be many bullets(pointers) of sentences as follows:

- In particular to Teachers Bullying (Oct): 201720/11/20
- In particular to Staff Being Crazy (Nov): 2016/22/1021
- Recurring feedback on Students Truancy (Dec): 201711/12/12

I am already able to iterate between the bullets(paragraph objects) and get each sentence;

But what I want to know is... Is there a way to underline words **between** 'In particular to' or 'Recurring feedback on' up until ':' has occurred ?

**The codes are as such:**

Dim objParagraph As Paragraph, rangeStart As Integer, rangeEnd As Integer

For Each objParagraph In Selection.Range.Paragraphs
  If objParagraph.Range.Text Like "Recurring*" Then

```
rangeStart = Len("Recurring feedback on ") +1
```

Else

```
rangeStart = Len("In particular to ") +1
```

End If

rangeEnd = Len(Left(objParagraph.Range.Text, 
             InStr(objParagraph.Range.Text,":"-1))

'Format Range(start,end).underlined = true ?

Next objParagraph

**Sorry for bad English :/**

Comment: Is there a way? Yes there is. Using `Find` to find "In particular to ", store range end in variable, find `:`, store range start, format range(first end, second start) as underlined. Try and come back once you have a code attempt. Use macro recorder if unsure where to begin.

Comment: Ah! , I've used:
Len("In particular to ") , to return me the length 

& Len(Left(objectParagraph.Range.Text), InStr(objectParagraph.Range.Text, ":")-1)) 
which returns me the length of words before ":" occurs.... I can't however manage to format range  as mentioned in your solution :( Sorry i'm fresh to vba.

Comment: `I've used` - So you *do* have some code. Please show that you've tried and *what* you've tried. We don't simply *provide* ready-made code here. We help you with *yours*.

Comment: Sorry I'm working in a VPN environment, and its really hard to post codes here, or even extract from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I've tinkered a bit and the following should get you going.

```
Dim ran As Range, rstart As Long, rend As Long

Set ran = ActiveDocument.Content

With ran
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .text = "In particular to "
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
    End With

    While .Find.Found
        rstart = .End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.text = ":"
        .Find.Execute
        rend = .Start
        ActiveDocument.Range(rstart, rend).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.text = "In particular to "
        .Find.Execute
    Wend

    .Find.text = "Recurring feedback on "
    .Find.Execute
    While .Find.Found
        rstart = .End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.text = ":"
        .Find.Execute
        rend = .Start
        ActiveDocument.Range(rstart, rend).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.text = "Recurring feedback on "
        .Find.Execute
    Wend

End With
```

In case you wish to restrict the processing to a table, just replace

`Set ran = ActiveDocument.Content`

with

`Set ran = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range`

Comment: Thank you so very much buddy! :)

Comment: @zixuan Please let everyone know if this worked for you. If so, please accept the answer so your problem is marked as "solved" in case anyone else is looking for such a solution.